# Memory allocation of priority queues

Tags: data-structures, heaps

So, i faced this question during a pratice quiz [image]

i have no idea why " all of the elements are located contiguously in memory " wrong!!
My logic is that priority queues are made of binary heaps and binary heaps are made of arrays ( according to introduction to algorithms by CLRS ) , so this means that elements are located contiguously in memory is true for PQ since it's true for arrays
so, what am i doing wrong ?!

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An associative dictionary is any data structure which maps keys to values. Binary search trees, hash tables, and B-trees are all examples of associative dictionaries. It is incorrect to say that an associative dictionary must be a binary search tree.

Similarly, a priority queue is any data structure which allows insertion in any order and removal in priority order. A binary heap is an example of a priority queue, but it is incorrect to say that a priority queue must be a binary heap.

There are lots of other data structures which implement priority queues, including n-ary heaps (for n greater than 2), binomial heaps, Fibonacci heaps, Brodal queues, van Emde Boas trees, and many more besides.

And that's leaving aside the issue that a binary heap doesn't strictly need to be stored in contiguous memory. Any storage scheme can be used as long as it can be indexed like an array and supports $O(1)$ access time.